# Grid appears empty when using schema.data

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, schema

I have an issue which I believe is very trivial, yet has been frustrating me for days.

```
<div id="grid"></div> 
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "http://localhost/public/ajax/user/cultures.json",
                    pageSize: 10,
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data"
            },
            columns: [
                { field: 'oname' },
                { field: 'oculture_code' }
            ],
            height: 500,
            scrollable: true,
            selectable: true,
            sortable: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

A sample of the data I receive from the data I receive from the server is:

```
{
    "total":136,
    "data":
    [
         {"oculture_code":"af-ZA","oname":"Afrikaans - South Africa"},
         {"oculture_code":"ar-AE","oname":"Arabic - United Arab Emirates"},
         {"oculture_code":"ar-BH","oname":"Arabic - Bahrain"},
         ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

The above does not work as the grid initially does some processing but in the end it appears emtpy. I tried with the response:

```
[{"oculture_code":"af-ZA","oname":"Afrikaans - South Africa"}, ...]
```

and without using the schema and the grid is filled with data. 
Adding the schema with the latter data also still works. It is when I modify the json response that something goes wrong.

I wish to use the schema as I am planning to add server side paging. But this is stopping me from moving forward. Am I doing something completely wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you have defined `schema` outside `dataSource` while it is part of the `DataSource` definition. It should be:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read    : "cultures.json",
            pageSize: 10,
            dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        schema    : {
            data : "data"
        }
    },
    columns   : [
        { field: 'oname' },
        { field: 'oculture_code' }
    ],
    height    : 500,
    scrollable: true,
    selectable: true,
    sortable  : true
});
```